# typescript: How to write an arrow function with type declaration?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to do the equivalent of the following JavaScript code in typescript:

```
  users.map( item => (
    { name: item.name,
      email: item.email,
      ...item.user
    }
  ));
```

So, `users` is like:

```
users = [
  {
    name: "John",
    email: "john@msn"
    user: {
            age: 56,
            gender: "Male", 
            address: "...", 
            sport: "basketball"
          }
  }, 
  ...
  
]
```

I'm trying to convert it to:

```
users = [
  {
    name: "John",
    email: "john@msn",
    age: 56,
    gender: "Male", 
    address: "...", 
    sport: "basketball"
  }, 

  ...
  
]
```

I thought I was supposed to declare the type of the parameter directly after the parameter and the type of the return value before the arrow:

```
  users.map( (item:object):object => (
    { name: item.name,
      email: item.email,
      ...item.user
    }
  ));
```

But this does not work.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` in typescript without any type like in JavaScript **But**
if you want to use type, you need to create an interface. Note that object does not have property `name` , `email` and other properties, so if you use object the `ts` compiler raise an error:

Try this one:

```
interface personlaInfo{
age: number,
gender: string, 
address: string, 
sport: string
}

interface user{
  name:string,
  email: string
  personlaInfo:personlaInfo;
}

var users : Array<user> = [
  {
    name: "John",
    email: "john@msn",
    personlaInfo: {
            age: 56,
            gender: "Male", 
            address: "...", 
            sport: "basketball"
          }
  }  
]

 var f = users.map( (item:user) => (
    { name: item.name,
      email: item.email,
      ...item.personlaInfo
    }
  ));
```

[PlaygroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&ssl=34&ssc=18&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgA7QM4HsQBs4CSIMWA3gFBwDmEAXMiAK4C2ARtADTk0gAm09DGCigqHZJV68oEDBkHDR48hlRYoYBSJBVyAX3LlQkWIhSMM0CsgZxmdIdrHkbEZnGC4tol2kw58IhJadChsPEJiLABufUMANzgoZAtMZHoAQSgoOABPAB5UqAA%20ZABeZABtX2sbW3t6ACIAKSwACxBGrjrkNw8vZEaAK3aQAAFmDE7uutDwwKj6Wp6V5Go6ZABWADYZ1Z6efigmgFk4XAguiX2VuCkZOSaAOher3xubVXVNQdY4DAA1hAwH9cLhGu99gYbHobOQALqGZCJZIwcopSxhJ7uVAACmQuOAkGYtCKAEpyqVcZDSPUNkS3E8QHYIHs6n1PPQGcwnhzcGybC8ntynnMApESJDocgyWTYr4EDhsBcnrgsFRcTA5UA)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the second `object`, in this case TypeScript can infer it, like this:

```
  users.map((item:object) => (
    { name: item.name,
      email: item.email,
      ...item.user
    }
  ));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define interfaces for your data type and use them in map like below:

```
interface MyUser {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    age: number;
    gender: string;
    address: string;
    sport: string;
}

interface UserInfo {
    age: number;
    gender: string;
    address: string;
    sport: string;
}


interface User {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    user: UserInfo
}


const users:Array<User> = [
    {
      name: "John",
      email: "john@msn",
      user: {
              age: 56,
              gender: "Male", 
              address: "...", 
              sport: "basketball"
            }
    }, 
    {
        name: "John1",
        email: "john1@msn",
        user: {
                age: 26,
                gender: "Male", 
                address: "...", 
                sport: "basketball"
              }
      }, 
  ];

const my_users = users.map( (item:User):MyUser => (
    { name: item.name,
      email: item.email,
      ...item.user
    }
  ));

  console.log(my_users)
```